# easiest way to convert .NET project from 4.5 to 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .NET application that I built in 4.5, which has references to a bunch of libraries that were built in 4.5, which themselves have references to 4.5, etc.  A user group that I'm trying to distribute the application to is having problems running the executable because they have 4.0 installed; in particular, they're getting a MissingMethodException:

```
Method not found: 'System.Type System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID(System.Guid)'.
```

Because we may have trouble getting each user upgraded to 4.5 (as none of them have admin permissions on their machines and this would require a separate upgrade request for each user), I'm looking at finding an easy way to rebuild the project as 4.0.  This seems to require that I rebuild every library and its referenced libraries in 4.0; is there an easier way to do this than going through each library one by one and building a 4.0 version?  I'm thinking maybe like a one-click option for "Rebuild all referenced libraries in target framework" or something like that.

Comment: No, you'll have to change the Framework target on each individual project.  I supposed you could write a little program that uses XDocument to change the project files, I doubt it is faster.  Do make sure your client is aware what version you've tested and can support.  Which has little to do with what version you can build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have dependencies on .Net 4.5 DLLs then you will need to also get .Net 4.0 versions of those if you want to successfully downgrade your project.  A .Net project can only reference .Net DLLs up to the same version of .Net as the referencing assembly.

The easiest way to do this is to use something like [NuGet](http://nuget.org) to manage your dependencies.  Note that when you change the target framework version of your project in VS you will need to uninstall and re-install dependencies with NuGet as NuGet does not automatically do this for you when you change the target framework version.

Of course if all the dependencies are to your own code and you aren't publishing this through a dependency management system like NuGet you will need to downgrade all your other code to .Net 4.0 as well

Answer (score 4):

When I use Visual Studio, I right click on the project, change the framework, fix the References and recompile. Usually straight forward.

Comment: This would work if the project didn't have dependencies on other 4.5 DLLs.  When I recompile, each reference gives me this warning: `The primary reference "NameOfReferencedDLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".` and all the classes from the reference are unavailable.

Comment: So, you have to do the same with the dependencies first.

Answer (score 1):

Please, have a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to correctly switch your project to a lower target framework without problems! It is a little bit outdated for what concerns versions, but the process is the same described!

Comment: This won't work because I have references to other 4.5 projects, see my response to Andrew above.

Comment: You have to rebuild your references to a 4.0 framework, so... or keep the project under 4.5 framework. You need to find a way to have framework consistency across all the references and projects in this case.
Earlier frameworks can be good (for example project is 4.5 and references 3.5) but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on my experience. I had an application initially created in .net framework 4.5 but I wanted to convert it in .net framework 4.0. I created new project initially created 4.0 and then I did copy and paste of all the forms and controls of my previous application and it works. Framework 4.5 is using Aero2 and 4.0 is Aero... Good Luck :)